# Creating a ROS msg and srv - Tutorial

Tags: ros, tutorial, cmake, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I have the same problem as mentioned here: [Error using rosmsg in "Creating msg and srv" Tutorial](http://answers.ros.org/question/197495/error-using-rosmsg-in-creating-msg-and-srv-tutorial/)

In section 2.2 of this tutorial when typing the command

> $ rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num

I don't get

> init64 num

but

> Unable to load msg
> [beginner_tutorials/Num]: Cannot
> locate message [Num]: unknown package
> [beginner_tutorials] on search path
> ...

In the other thread the solution is: I should simply run:

> $ cd ~/catkin_ws/
> then
> > $ catkin_make

But there I get the Error:

> CMake Error at /home/user/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials/cmake/beginner_tutorials-genmsg.cmake:3 (message):
> Could not find messages which
> '/home/user/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg/Num.msg' depends on.
> Did you forget to specify generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)?
>
> Cannot locate message [init64] in
> package [beginner_tutorials] with
> paths
> [['/home/user/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/msg']]
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:304
> (include)
> beginner_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:68 (generate_messages)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "/home/user/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
> Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

What do I do wrong. I changed the CMakeList.txt exactly as said in the tutorials and checked it a lot of times. And I put in

> catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)

Can anybody help me out here?
Thanks!!

Edit:

Here is the CMakeLists.txt (I removed the commented parts):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)
add_message_files(
   FILES
   Num.msg
)
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES 
   std_msgs
)
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

And here the package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>beginner_tutorials</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The package for beginners</description>

  
  <maintainer email="user@todo.todo">user</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>


  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  
  <export>
    
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203481/creating-a-ros-msg-and-srv---tutorial/) by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2015-02-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-02-20**:
Did you save the file as said iin the tutorial?
Could you please entirely post your `CMakeLists.txt` und `package.xml` ?

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-02-20**:
Thanks for your comment!
Yes, I saved it here: ~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-02-20**:
I put in both files in the edit above.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-20**:
Does your `Num.msg` file actually say `init64 num`? It should say `int64 num` (you have an extra 'i'). That typing error would explain why you are getting the "Cannot locate message [init64]" when running `catkin_make`

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-02-20**:
And what happen if you type simply:

```
$ rosmsg show Num
```

?????
without the folder name

**Comment by [bluefish](https://answers.ros.org/users/21682/bluefish/) on 2015-02-20**:
Thanks so much **javisschultz** and **Andromeda**!! I really put in that extra "i".
And I tried to find that error for hours. So stupid....

Sorry for bothering you with that and thanks again!!

**Comment by [JarvisRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/28749/jarvisrobot/) on 2016-12-07**:
I face the same problem.  I changed the CMakeList.txt exactly as said in the tutorials and checked it a lot of times. When I try to `~/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials$ rosmsg show Num`,it returns `Could not find msg 'Num'`. Can anybody help me out here? Thanks!!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-12-08**:
The command should be `rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a typo: `init64` instead of `int64`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3